# ES , Group By field ORDER by date

Tags: elasticsearch

How would one accomplish the following in ES 6.*

In **sql** we can do this...

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `title_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `added` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `title_id` (`t_id`),
)
```

Query :  I want to get the latest rows grouped by title_id ordered by added.

```
 SELECT *, max(added) as max_date FROM table 
 GROUP BY title_id ORDER By max_date DESC LIMIT 0,20
```

Now in **ES**

ES Mapping :

```
$mapping =[


        'title_id' => ['type' => 'integer'],
        'name' => ['type' => 'keyword'],
        'added' => [
            'type' => 'date',
            'format' =>'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'
        ],
]
```

What would be the best way to do this in ES ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use field collapsing.
Elastic search documentation defines it as "Allows to collapse search results based on field values. The collapsing is done by selecting only the top sorted document per collapse key. For instance the query below retrieves the best tweet for each user and sorts them by number of likes"

Mapping

```
PUT testindex8
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title_id": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "name":{
        "type": "text"
      },
      "addedOn":{
        "type":"date",
        "format":"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Data

```
 [
      {
        "_index" : "testindex8",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "WQ8hEW0BnGA1T2ysR5EU",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "title_id" : 1,
          "name" : "T1_1",
          "addedOn" : "2019-01-01T03:00:00"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "testindex8",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Wg8hEW0BnGA1T2ysZJF1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "title_id" : 1,
          "name" : "T1_2",
          "addedOn" : "2019-01-01T04:00:00"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "testindex8",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Ww8hEW0BnGA1T2ysnpH1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "title_id" : 1,
          "name" : "T1_2",
          "addedOn" : "2019-01-01T01:00:00"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "testindex8",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "XA8hEW0BnGA1T2yswpHL",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "title_id" : 2,
          "name" : "T2_1",
          "addedOn" : "2019-01-01T01:00:00"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "testindex8",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "XQ8hEW0BnGA1T2ys3pFr",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "title_id" : 2,
          "name" : "T2_2",
          "addedOn" : "2019-01-01T03:00:00"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "testindex8",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Xg8hEW0BnGA1T2ys8JFr",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "title_id" : 2,
          "name" : "T2_3",
          "addedOn" : "2019-01-01T05:00:00"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Query:

```
GET testindex8/_search
{
  "collapse": {
    "field": "title_id"
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "addedOn": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Result:

```
[
      {
        "_index" : "testindex8",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Xg8hEW0BnGA1T2ys8JFr",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "title_id" : 2,
          "name" : "T2_3",
          "addedOn" : "2019-01-01T05:00:00"
        },
        "fields" : {
          "title_id" : [
            2
          ]
        },
        "sort" : [
          1546318800000
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "testindex8",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Wg8hEW0BnGA1T2ysZJF1",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "title_id" : 1,
          "name" : "T1_2",
          "addedOn" : "2019-01-01T04:00:00"
        },
        "fields" : {
          "title_id" : [
            1
          ]
        },
        "sort" : [
          1546315200000
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks ,  exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad could be of help